# How to download with wget without following links with parameters

Tags: linux, unix, wget

I'm trying to download two sites for inclusion on a CD:

```
http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki
http://www.boinc-wiki.info
```

The problem I'm having is that these are both wikis. So when downloading with e.g.:

```
wget -r -k -np -nv -R jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tif http://www.boinc-wiki.info/
```

I do get a **lot of files** because it also follows links like ...?action=edit ...?action=diff&version=...

Does somebody know a way to get around this?

I just want the current pages, without images, and without diffs etc.

P.S.:

```
wget -r -k -np -nv -l 1 -R jpg,jpeg,png,gif,tif,pdf,ppt http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/TitleIndex
```

This worked for berkeley but boinc-wiki.info is still giving me trouble :/

P.P.S:

I got what appears to be the most relevant pages with:

```
wget -r -k -nv  -l 2 -R jpg,jpeg,png,gif,tif,pdf,ppt http://www.boinc-wiki.info
```

Comment: No need to cross post between superuser and serverfault http://serverfault.com/questions/156045/how-to-download-with-wget-without-following-links-with-parameters

Comment: Where should I have posted it?

Comment: this is the right place. It's not a server question.

Comment: Still I got the better answers at serverfault ;)

Answer (score 5):

The new version of ***wget (v.1.14)*** solves all these problems.

You have to use the new option `--reject-regex=....` to handle query strings.

Note that I couldn't find the new manual that includes these new options, so you have to use the help command `wget --help > help.txt`

Answer (score 5):

```
wget --reject-regex '(.*)\?(.*)' http://example.com
```

(`--reject-type posix` by default).  Works only for recent (>=1.14) versions of `wget` though, according to other comments.

Beware that it seems you can use `--reject-regex` only once per `wget` call.  That is, you have to use `|` in a single regex if you want to select on several regex :

```
wget --reject-regex 'expr1|expr2|…' http://example.com
```

Comment: Could be true about the version requirement. I had v1.12 and the option was not valid. After upgrade to v1.15 it was.

Comment: Regex alternation using the `|` ("pipe") symbol isn't working for me with GNU Wget 1.16.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -R "*?action=*"
```

This will exclude anything which contains `?action=` in its name.

Comment: "Note, too, that query strings (strings at the end of a URL beginning with a question mark (‘?’) are not included as part of the filename for accept/reject rules, even though these will actually contribute to the name chosen for the local file. It is expected that a future version of Wget will provide an option to allow matching against query strings."

Comment: Hmm, I must have missed that.  It looks like you can't do this with wget then if it doesn't even know that they are different files.  I suggest a different program.

Answer (score -3):

I'd say that leeching a public wiki site is bad practice, because it puts additional load on it.

If a wiki is public and the site owners don't mind sharing the content, they usually provide a downloadable backend (database or whatever) dump. So you would just download the data pack, set up a local instance of the same wiki engine, import the data into it and have a local copy. After that, if you wish, you can do the leeching locally.

Comment: there is -w seconds. e.g. -w 5.  http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html#Download-Options